# CakePHP 3: Forbidden Error when sending Ajax Post request of jQuery-Tabledit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got 403 Forbidden Error while trying to implement jQuery-Tabledit (https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/) on my table. Upon researching, it seems the problem is related to authorization, however I have no clue how to fix. I use neither AuthComponent nor SecurityComponent.

**Template/User/index.ctp**

```
<div class="user index large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <h3><?= __('User') ?></h3>
    <table id="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($user as $user): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($user->email) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<?= $this->Html->script('/js/table_edit_test') ?>
```

**webroot/js/table_edit_test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table').Tabledit({
        url:"/user/testing",
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'name'], 
            [2, 'email']]
        },

        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },

        onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

        onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
            console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
            console.log(action);
            console.log(serialize);
        },
    });
});
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function index() {
    $user = $this->paginate($this->User);

    $this->set(compact('user'));
}

public function testing() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if($this->request->is('Ajax')) {
        $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

        if($input["action"] === 'edit') {
            $user = $this->User->get($input["id"]);
            $user->name = $input["name"];
            $user->email = $input["email"];
            $this->User->save($user);
        }

        return json_encode($input);
    }
}
```

**AppController.php**

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    /*
     * Enable the following component for recommended CakePHP security settings.
     * see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html
     */
    //$this->loadComponent('Security');
}
```

Debug Screenshot:
[image: Console]

[image: Debugger]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your controller should return a response object, not text. `return json_encode($input);` should be `return $this->response->withStringBody(json_encode($input));`.

Comment: There are some possibilities about 403. One thing you need to consider about CSRF. cakephp 3 is more secure and followed modern PHP. You should try to `X-CSRF-Token` like `headers : {'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()},`

Comment: @GregSchmidt Had fixed that. Unfortunately, the 403 error still exists.

Comment: @502_Geek I had confirmed: it's definitely CSRF's cause. I was testing various CSRF header methods and one of them WORKED... for maybe 5s. It didn't work anymore after reloading the page, and if there wasn't definitely change in my database I would consider it a dream. I currently go through about 7 opening tabs, changing my code back and fort hoping to find that magic again. My suspect is the code 
`var jqXHR = $.post(settings.url, serialize, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               //some function
            }, 'json');` in *jquery.tabledit.js*

Comment: Unsuccessful attempts: wrote `$.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
       }
   });`
before $.post(); wrote `var jqXHR = $.post(settings.url, $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val(), serialize, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { //some function }, 'json');`; in **table_edit_test.js**: wrote`beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader(‘X-CSRF-Token’, $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
  },`; same methods as above, but change `$('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()` to `<?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')); ?>` (produced error)

Comment: Well, there are several method to add `_csrfToken` while sending ajax. As you mentioned earlier, you can add `beforeSend` or you can put at `key:value` approach like `headers:{}`. Glad to know you found out the csrf issue after you got my comment. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 403 Error comes from CSRF-Token, which was automatically added in CakePHP version 3.6 and above even if you didn't choose to use the component. Kudos to 502_Geek for helping me find out the cause. My fix:

- In **src/Template/Layout/default.ctp**: add in header

```
<head>
<!--Get CSRF-Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken') ?>" />
</head>
```

- In **webroot/js/jquery.tabledit.js**: change `$.post()` to `$.ajax()` and add CSRF-Token to header:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: settings.url,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data: serialize,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        if (action === settings.buttons.edit.action) {
            $lastEditedRow.removeClass(settings.dangerClass).addClass(settings.warningClass);
            setTimeout(function() {
                //$lastEditedRow.removeClass(settings.warningClass);
                $table.find('tr.' + settings.warningClass).removeClass(settings.warningClass);
            }, 1400);
        }

        settings.onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

- In **webroot/js/table_edit_test.js**: use full link for URL:

```
url: 'https://localhost/user/testing',
```

Note for any newbie who begins to learn JavaScript like me:

- F12 -> Console: read console.log()
- F12 -> Network -> Click on file with error status -> Params: read $_POST from Ajax
- F12 -> Network -> Click on file with error status -> Response: read main reason for error (CSRF mismatched, Object not found, etc)